# New brush strokes keep changing the opacity/color of previous strokes

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, brush

In the image below, I showcase the problem:

[image]

Brush strokes change color when covering each other/interacting,  when I go over the same area in more than one stroke, things  get "whitened" and I'm using the simple hard round brush. What can I do to stop that, is there a way to solve this problem so that I get a smooth, consistent look with multiple strokes? Thank for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your brush `Blending Mode` setting (tool bar on top): it's probably set to something that's not `Normal`:

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU so much, you totally saved me, that was the problem!!!!! I must have accidentally changed it from normal to screen :)

Comment: @Stamios there are shortcuts to set Blending Modes that usually aren't well known to public: `Alt+Shift+Letter`. For Screen it's `Alt+Shift+S` — easy to miss something like `Ctrl+Shift+S` and accidentally enable it